# Mapping format on elasticsearch

Tags: json, indexing, elasticsearch, mapping

I'm to upload a json document to my server via elasticsearch but i wanted to map it before i upload it but i keep getting a search phase execution exception error.
The json data looks like this

```
{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-73.20266100000001,45.573647]},"properties":{"persistent_id":"XVCPFsbsqB7h4PrxEtCU3w==","timestamp":1408216040000,"tower_id":"10.48.66.178"}}
```

So far i've tried this as my mapping. Im not sure what i am doing wrong...

```
curl –XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/carrier/_search?q=coordinates?pretty=true' -d'
{ “geometry”: {
“type” : {“type” : “string”},
“coordinates” : {“type”  : “geo_point”}
},
“properties” : { 
“persistent_id” : {“type” : “string”},
“timestamp”: { “type” : “long”},
“tower_id” : {“type” : “string”}
}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here. First of all you need to use [put mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) request instead of search request. The body of the request has to start with the name of the type followed by the list of `properties` (fields) that you add. The second problem is that you probably copied the example from some documentation where all ascii quotes (`"`) were replaced with replaced with their fancy unicode versions (`“` and `”`) and dash in front of the `XPUT` parameter looks like n-dash `–` instead of normal dash `-`. You need to replace all fancy quotes and dashes with their ascii versions. So, all together the working statement should look like this (assuming `doc` as your document type):

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/carrier/doc/_mapping' -d '{
    "doc": {
        "properties": {
            "geometry": {
                "properties": {
                    "type": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "coordinates": {
                        "type": "geo_point"
                    }
                }
            },
            "properties": {
                "properties": {
                    "persistent_id": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "timestamp": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "tower_id": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}'
```

then you can add document like this:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/carrier/doc/1' -d '{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-73.20266100000001,45.573647]},"properties":{"persistent_id":"XVCPFsbsqB7h4PrxEtCU3w==","timestamp":1408216040000,"tower_id":"10.48.66.178"}}'
```

Please note that in order to add the mapping you might need to delete and recreate the index if you already tried to add documents to this index and the mapping was already created.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I didnt even notice the ""

Comment: Also just out of curiosity, how would i go about doing a search for lets say coordinates

Comment: That should be a different question ;) There is a couple of ways. You can use [geo distance](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-filter.html) filter, for example.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're using the `_search` endpoint in order to install your mapping.

You have to use the `_mapping` endpoint instead, like this:

```
curl –XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/carrier/_mapping/geometry' -d '{
    ...your mapping...
}'
```